# Targetting 3rd child article and then nested DIV within it

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to target every 1st and 3rd article in this list and then tweak the CSS of the DIV which is sat within the article selector. How can I do this? My nth child stuff in jQuery is not working - I know its possible in CSS too - but jQuery solution is more universal to more browsers...?

```
<div class="blogFeed">
    <article>
        <div class="threeCols"></div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="threeCols"></div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="threeCols"></div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="threeCols"></div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="threeCols"></div>
    </article>
</div>
```

So I want to make CSS of `1st / 4th / 7th` - etc 1n+3 `margin-left:0px` and make the CSS of `3rd / 6th / 9th etc 1n+2` `margin-right:0px`

So the articles sit in 3 cols - so every 1/4/7 etc inner `.threeCols` div needs no LHS margin.., and every 3/6/9 etc inner `.threeCols` div needs no RHS margin...

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you post enough of your CSS that we can replicate your layout?

Comment: I'm not at all clear on why CSS doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8908d9sh/

Comment: It's not JS task, use just CSS.

Comment: And your first and second paragraphs seem to contradict each other. Please simplify and clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nth-child`:

```
.blogFeed article:nth-child(3n) div {background: red;} /* 3, 6, 9th element */
.blogFeed article:nth-child(3n+1) div {background: green;} /* 1, 4, 7th element */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvubwm4d/1/

Comment: How do I target the 1st/4th/7th div using nth?

Comment: @dubbs: I updated my answer a while ago, see the update. It's `3n+1`.

Comment: Ace - thanks: Confirmed answer is: $(".blogFeed article:nth-child(3n+1) .threeCols").css("margin-left", "0px");
$(".blogFeed article:nth-child(3n) .threeCols").css("margin-right", "0px");

Comment: @dubbs: Forget on JS here, put that into your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I would *strongly* echo recommendations to use CSS for this (compatibility for `:nth-child()` selectors is pretty good, unless you're supporting IE8 (partial support) and lower (no support)):

```
/* the 'left' column: */
article:nth-child(3n + 1) div {
  background-color: blue;
}
/* the 'right' column: */
article:nth-child(3n) div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}

article:nth-child(3n + 1) div {
  background-color: blue;
}

article:nth-child(3n) div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="blogFeed">
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

But, if you must use jQuery:

```
// independently styling the 'left' and 'right' columns: */
$('article:nth-child(3n + 1) div').css({
  backgroundColor : 'blue'
});

$('article:nth-child(3n) div').css({
  backgroundColor : 'red'
});
```

```js
$('article:nth-child(3n + 1) div').css({
  backgroundColor : 'blue'
});

$('article:nth-child(3n) div').css({
  backgroundColor : 'red'
});
```

```css
article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blogFeed">
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Or:, given that it's easier to update elements' presentation based on their class-names (specifically removing/adding) rather than using `css()` (which adds inline styles, with the `style` attribute) it's far more sensible to use `addClass()`:

```
// selecting all <div> elements that are
// in an <article> element, and calling
// the addClass() method:
$('article div').addClass(function(i){
  // Note that CSS is 1-based, JavaScript is 0-based.

  // if the result of i + 1 divided by 3 is zero:
  if ( (i + 1) % 3 === 0) {
    // we return the 'rightColumn' class-name:
    return 'rightColumn';
    // if i is equal to 0 then it's the first-child,
    // or if i divided by 3 is zero then it must
    // be in the first 'column' of the 'row':
  } else if ( i === 0 || i % 3 === 0) {
    return 'leftColumn';
  }
});
```

```js
$('article div').addClass(function(i){
  if ( (i + 1) % 3 === 0) {
    return 'rightColumn';
  } else if ( i === 0 || i % 3 === 0) {
    return 'leftColumn';
  }
});
```

```css
article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
.leftColumn {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.rightColumn {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blogFeed">
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

In plain JavaScript, you could use:

```
// Converting the NodeList (from querySelectorAll()) into
// array, using Array.prototype.slice():
var articleDivs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('article div'), 0);

// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
// that Array; within the function the first
// argument (here: 'div') is the array-element of
// the array over which we're iterating, the second
// argument (here: 'index') is the index of that element
// within the array:
articleDivs.forEach(function (div, index) {
  // the logic is exactly the same as above:
  if ( (index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
    // but we're using the Element.classList API
    // to add the relevant class-name(s):
    div.classList.add('rightColumn');
  } else if (index === 0 || index % 3 === 0) {
    div.classList.add('leftColumn');
  }
});
```

```js
var articleDivs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('article div'), 0);

articleDivs.forEach(function (div, index) {
  if ( (index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
    div.classList.add('rightColumn');
  } else if (index === 0 || index % 3 === 0) {
    div.classList.add('leftColumn');
  }
});
```

```css
article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
.leftColumn {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.rightColumn {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blogFeed">
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="threeCols"></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:nth-child()` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)<sup>[compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child)</sup>.
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css).